# Yii2: The query count function is slow, when distinct value

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I wrote a query with join ( hasMany() ) relation.
I want to fetch distinct value and need count for the pagination.

But when set the distinct true, count becomes slow.

```
$query = Post::find();
$query->joinWith( [ 'tags' ] )->where( [ 'tags.tag_id' => 1 ] );
$query->distinct();

$pages = new Pagination( [ 'totalCount' => $query->count(), 'pageSize' => 25, 'page' => 1 ] );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need distinct()

I am reasonably sure that if you remove distinct everything will work ok. Each post will be there just 1 time. That is because of the way Active records handles things.

Comment: No, I am getting the duplicate values.